# Raw access of SPI Master in Linux Driver for SPI-device access

Tags: linux-device-driver, spi

I am in process of writing a Linux Driver that is required to control two SPI devices (on separate SPI masters) and one I2C device. For the I2C Device, I was able to abstract out the I2C-slave access by using equivalent of below code and control it in my Driver,

```c
struct i2c_adapter *adap;
struct i2c_msg msg;

adap = i2c_get_adapter(<bus-ID>);
<define 'msg'>
i2c_transfer(adap, &msg, 1);
i2c_put_adapter(adap);
```

Are there any equivalent routines for getting the handle to SPI master and for performing Read/Write access on a connected SPI-slave? I know how to get one SPI handle in the driver using `struct spi_device_id` and `struct spi_driver`, but I do not know how to get access to two SPI devices belonging to different SPI masters in a single Driver.

I know that I may be missing something fundamental. Getting some code references will help a lot.

Comment: As far as. I can see you need four drivers.

Comment: Yes, one top level driver for my Device, one for I2C and two for SPI. For I2C, I was able to get away by using routines equivalent of above. But looks like, for SPI, I need to write drivers and export required routines as symbols.

Comment: It’s unclear in your question what the devices they are and how hardware design looks like. In the Linux kernel traditionally exporting symbols is a bad idea and you need kinda framework(s) that will unify all this together.

Comment: One is RF-Transceiver Chip with SPI bus for programming registers. This needs clock inputs, that are generated using an I2C programmable Clock buffer IC and third one is an SPI I/O expander to control the Reset line of the Transceiver IC. Within the Transceiver driver, I need to now plug in calls to control the clocks (I2C) and the Transceiver reset lines (SPI).

Comment: Clock provider needs: a) driver to support hardware; b) be a clock provider (see _driver/clk/_ folder). Reset similar, see _drivers/reset/_. So, you utilize Common Clock and Reset frameworks. And you need at least one driver per hardware. In the main  driver you request clock by it's name (I suppose you have some kind of device tree / ACPI for the description of your setup) and reset line the same.

Comment: Are these controllers part of a plug-in card (e.g PCI/PCIe) for a generic system, or part of an embedded system for which you have complete control over the hardware and kernel configuration? If you control the kernel config, you may be able to configure in existing drivers for the controllers.